# Rails/MySQL CURDATE Query with both created and updated at

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

hi guys i am really new to sql so please be gentle with me on this one. i am trying to run a Query that will pull all records that have been either created_at or updated_at within the last two weeks.

i did some reading at this is what i have so far

```
SELECT * FROM sms_development.scores WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE() OR DATE(updated_at) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

this looks really huge and its not dry at all. and its not working for some reason. if i enter it into MySQL workbench it give me a green light but i dont know if i have made a gramatical error or something. but no records are pulled.

any advice or techniques that are helpful are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do as much of this through Rails finders as possible; they're at least partially portable to other data storage engines, so if you, say, switch from SQLite to Postgres you won't have to rewrite (as much) code.

I would do this like so:

```
Score.where('created_at > ? OR updated_at > ?', DateTime.now - 2.weeks, DateTime.now - 2.weeks).all
```